# Unable to install glib2 gem on Amazon elastic beanstalk instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I am unable to install the glib2 gem on my amazon instance. I have tried to install the libglib2.0-dev library, to no avail, and have been trying to figure this out for the past hour.

Here is the output to the terminal

```
 ec2-user@ip-172-31-26-234 glib2-3.0.7]$ gem install glib2 -v '3.0.7'     
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing glib2:
            ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160303-29330-tykkxw.rb extconf.rb
checking for --enable-debug-build option... no
checking for -Wall option to compiler... yes
checking for -Waggregate-return option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wcast-align option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wextra option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wformat=2 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Winit-self option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wlarger-than-65500 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-declarations option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-format-attribute option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-include-dirs option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-noreturn option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-prototypes option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wnested-externs option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wold-style-definition option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wpacked option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wpointer-arith option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wswitch-default option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wswitch-enum option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wundef option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wout-of-line-declaration option to compiler... no
checking for -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wwrite-strings option to compiler... yes
checking for rb_define_alloc_func() in ruby.h... yes
checking for rb_block_proc() in ruby.h... yes
checking for new allocation framework... yes
checking for attribute assignment... no
checking for Windows... no
checking for gobject-2.0 version (>= 2.12.0)... no
checking for pacman... no
checking for brew... no
checking for port... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --enable-debug-build
        --disable-debug-build
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-override-variables
        --without-override-variables

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.2.4/gems/glib2-3.0.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.2.4/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/glib2-3.0.7/gem_make.out
```

The mkmf.log file shows this error that I can see.

```
conftest.c:4:18: fatal error: node.h: No such file or directory
 #include "node.h"
                  ^
compilation terminated.
```

However, I do not know how to resolve this error.

I can post the whole mkmf.log file if needed.

Any help?